# Compute the expected value of a brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $X(t)$ is a brownian motion. Compute $E[X(1)X(5)X(7)]$.

I know that the brownian motion has independent increments, so if we could write $X(1)X(5)X(7)$ as such, then we could use the properties of the expected value.

Any suggestions? Is there another way?

Comment: i think $E\{B_t\}=0$

Comment: Could you elaborate? I know that $X(i)$ is normal with mean 0 for every $i$, but what about the product $X(1)X(5)X(7)$? I know that $E[X(1)X(5)X(7)]=E[X(1)]E[X(5)]E[X(7)]$ is not true.

Answer (score 0):

We know the distribution of the vector $V:=(X(7)-X(5), X(5)-X(1), X(1))$, since the increments are independent. Defining the function $f\colon (x,y,z)\mapsto (x+y+z)(y+z)z$, the wanted expectation is $\mathbb E\left[f(V)\right]$.